# Twitter StreamingAPI with Pusher

Tags: twitter, arduino, pusher

I am working on a project, which has a few dependencies. I would like to have your insights and best practices on a few matters.

1. Which is the right Twitter Streaming API to get the tweets from the authenticating user?
2. Does it make sense to hook that streaming API to Pusher and hook my Arduino on Pusher as well?
3. What is the best library to hook the streaming API to a Laravel backend?

I sincerely hope that this question is within the rules of StackOverflow, as I am not sure. I would really like to gain this information.

Answer (score 0):

1. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline
2. You can definitely easily hook an incoming feed from Twitter up with Pusher (see next answer). And Pusher does have an [Arduino library](https://github.com/krohling/ArduinoPusherClient) that should help you too.
3. Pusher has a solid [PHP library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server) so it will be easy to publish data from a Laravel application. The tricky part may be consuming the Twitter streaming API from Laravel and PHP.[Phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) claims to offer access to the streaming API from PHP.

If you could consider other technologies then there's an in-progress [Pusher + Twitter Streaming example](https://github.com/robhawkes/tweet-stats-api) that you could look at written in Node. There's also [this older example](https://github.com/ollieglass/pusher-d3-demo) that uses Python.

Comment: Thank you for your information! I indeed found Phirehose and it's great, only thing is, that I don't know how I should setup Phirehose correctly, as a webpage it is exceeding my rates and I read I have to set up Phirehose as a CLI in PHP?

I just need to know: how can I use Phirehose so Laravel can receive data from it?